# i18n module with email-templates

Tags: node.js, email, internationalization, nodemailer, email-templates

I have setup [nodemailer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemailer) to work with the [email-templates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/email-templates) module, using `ejs` as the render engine.

So far it works as intended, but, as with other sections of my app, I would also like to use the [i18n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/i18n) module to have my mail text translated in the same fashion as my app's rendered views.

Unfortunately, it isn't working. This is what I tried doing:

**example html.ejs:**

```
<h1><%= __('Hi') %>, <%= user.name %>!</h1>
```

**node code in the route:**

```
    // requires at the top
    var i18n = require('i18n');

    // (.....)

    // use template based sender to send a message
    sendMailTemplate({
        to: user.email,
        // EmailTemplate renders html and text but no subject so we need to
        // set it manually either here or in the defaults section of templateSender()
        subject: i18n.__('translatable subject')
    }, {
        user: user,
        __: i18n.__
    }, function(err, info){
        if(err){
           console.log('Error');
           console.log(err);
        }else{
            console.log('email sent');
            req.flash('info', i18n.__('mail sent to %s', user.email));
            done(err, 'done');                
        }
    });
    // other stuff...
```

Just a couple of things:

- In my mail's output, nothing borks - the string just isn't translated.
- I believe that simply passing `i18n`'s `__` function in the object going to the render engine should be enough to have it available to `ejs` and perform as intended, but I'm not sure. Any thoughts on this?
- I haven't `i18n.setLocale`, and so it supposedly defaults to english when `req.` (which is incidentally the language I'm seeing in my received email). Could this be the reason why it isn't translating as intended?

Any thought are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turns out I was right. `i18n` was indeed defaulting to english. I figured I should set the locale before passing it in to the templating engine and it worked.

I got the preferred accepted language using express.js's [req.accceptsLanguages()](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.acceptsLanguages) method. This isn't failproof, as there is no way to insure that this is indeed the user's native language (though in most cases, it should be).

Also, as I was using `i18n` in its global scope, that's the reason why it was defaulting to english. As such, I pass it to the templating engine aswell and then use it as indicated [here](https://github.com/mashpie/i18n-node):

```
__({phrase: 'Hello', locale: 'fr'}); // Salut
```

So, the final bit is something along the lines of this:

```
// requires at the top
var i18n = require('i18n');

// (.....)

// THIS IS NEW - it's from express.js
// returns a shorthand for the user's preferred locale: en, es, de, fr, pt, ...
var userLocale = req.acceptsLanguages()[1];

// use template based sender to send a message
sendMailTemplate({
    to: user.email,
    // EmailTemplate renders html and text but no subject so we need to
    // set it manually either here or in the defaults section of templateSender()
    subject: i18n.__({phrase: 'translatable subject', locale: userLocale}) // note the syntax here
}, {
    user: user,
    __: i18n.__,
    locale: userLocale      // THIS IS ALSO NEW
}, function(err, info){
    if(err){
       console.log('Error');
       console.log(err);
    }else{
        console.log('email sent');
        // also note the syntax here:
        req.flash('info', i18n.__({phrase: 'mail sent to %s', locale: userLocale}, user.email)); 
        done(err, 'done');                
    }
});
// other stuff...
```

Comment: Funilly, not sure why, even before using this syntax in the ejs email template, it was already being rendered with the correct locale. I think it must have something to do with having used it in the `subject` string before I passed it to the template.